# Volume of $\{(x,y,z)\in [a,b]\times \mathbb R^2:y^2+z^2\leq f(x)^2\}$ for a continuous function $f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, volume

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ be continuous. I want to calculate the Volume of $A=\{(x,y,z)\in [a,b]\times \mathbb R^2:y^2+z^2\leq f(x)^2\}$

So far I got this:

Using polar coodinates $(y=r\cos(\phi)$ and $y=r\sin(\phi)$) we have
$$\int_A1=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_a^b\int_0^{f(x)}r\text{ }drdxd\phi.$$

My first question: It this correct? Secondly, if this is indeed correct I need to integrate $f(x)^2$. How can I do that?

Comment: No real way to do that. Consider, for example, $f(x)=e^{x^2}$. Your substitution is wrong ($y$ and $z$, not $x$ and $y$). Other than that, I think it's ok.

Comment: Thanks, I edited it. But there must be some solution to this, since it is one of our task^^

Comment: There is certainly an expression for what you want. Doesn't mean the expression is *simple*.

Comment: There's no solution to $\int e^{2x^2} dx$. I think the purpose of this exercise was to get $\pi \int_a^b (f(x))^2 dx$, not to solve the integral (which is literally impossible in the general case)

Comment: @Adam Okay thank you, that may be the case. Shouldnt it be $2\pi$ instead of $\pi$?

Comment: @Marc No, because $\int rdr = r^2/2+c$

Comment: Oh, of course! Thanks